# How do I pass in a string variable into a ..loadRequest flutter controller that I received from another page thru MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, materialpageroute

This is my code:

```
class ArticleView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String blogUrl;

  ArticleView({required this.blogUrl,super.key});
  WebViewController controlla = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(blogUrl));
```

I am trying to get this string variable from the "home.dart" file...
Right here :

```
class BlogTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl, title, desc, url;
  BlogTile(
      {required this.imageUrl,
      required this.title,
      required this.desc,
      required this.url});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ArticleView(
                      blogUrl: url,
                    )));
      },
```

I have tried the above solution, but I am new to flutter, most resources I can find are outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a stateful widget so define the variable in top and in initState define the value of it

```dart
late WebViewController controlla;
void initState() {
 controlla = WebViewController()
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(blogUrl));
}
```

Comment: Glad it did. Please accept the answer so it might be helpful for others